# Java Regular Expression Escape Sequence

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I was trying to match the `example` in ,
`<p><a href="example/index.html">LinkToPage</a></p>`

With rubular.com I could get something like `<a href=\"(.*)?\/index.html\">.*<\/a>`.

I'll be using this in `Pattern.compile` in `Java`. I know that `\` has to be escaped as well, and I've come up with `<a href=\\\"(.*)?\\\/index.html\\\">.*<\\\/a>` and a few more variations but I'm getting it wrong. I tested on regexplanet. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: No escaping necessary here.  Just use `...=\"...` A backslash only needs to be escaped, when you actually want a backslash. And in a regex, you have to do it twice.

Comment: If it's an escaping issue, try printing your string to the command line to figure out what it thinks it is and correcting accordingly. All those backslashes can get annoying.

Comment: Eclipse indicates invalid escape sequence for `<a href=\"(.*)?\/index.html\">.*<\/a>`.

Comment: Since this is HTML, you should consider using an HTML parser... Like, for instance, jsoup.

Comment: You don't need \ before /

Comment: replace `...\/...` with `.../...`

Comment: @fge It is a list of 700-800 href. So I thought this would be simple

Comment: @Crocode it is not the question of size here; it is the question that when using regexes, you can easily match false positives; what if your pattern matches some text in a `<pre>` block? You have close to zero chance to write a regex eliminating all false positives... And this is why parsers exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"<a href=\"(.*)/index.html\">.*</a>"` in your Java code.

You only need to escape `"` because it's a Java string literal.

You don't need to escape `/`, because you aren't delimiting your regex with slashes (as you would be in Ruby).

Also, `(.*)?` makes no sense. Just use `(.*)`. `*` can already match "nothing", so there's no point in having the `?`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("<a href=\"(.*)?/index.html\">.*</a>");
```

That should fix your regex.  You do not need to escape the forward slashes.

However I am obligated to present you with the standard caution against parsing HTML with regex:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Java what to match and call Pattern.quote(str) to make it escape the correct things for you.